# Informix dbexport from AIX and dbimport to Windows

Tags: informix, aix

Is it possible to move an old Informix 4.10 database on a dying RS6000 AIX machine to a Windows server using dbexport? I can't find a lot of documentation on moving Informix across platforms. Is it possible to use dbexport on the AIX box and then use dbimport on a Windows box to load the DB?

If not dbexport, where can one find info on how to do this?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dbexport is one of the utilities available for moving data between different versions of Informix and is particularly useful where different OS platforms are involved. There is information relating to these utilities in the [Migration Guide](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.mig.doc/ids_mig_113.htm). The given URL relates to version 14.10 but many of the basic principles are the same.

Since your version 4.10 is so old some of the options for the dbexport command may not be available. For example, the -ss option to include information in the generated schema file about table extent sizes, locking mode and dbspaces may not be available. If you have sufficient disk space to run dbexport with the -o option to create a directory with the exported data then you could edit the generated schema file to add this information in before using dbimport on your target Windows server.

Comment: Thank you. I had read the migration guide but it didn't mention moving the exported file to a different operating system. It is also difficult to find documentation for such an old version.